# No 5th gear manual transmission

Tags: transmission

My 5th gear is out so I'm driving it in 4th. Would or could that cause transmission problems
2006 mercury milian

Comment: Why is 5th out? that may affect the rest of the gearbox, or it could just be a linkage adjustment...

Comment: Automatic or manual? And "out" as in how? Grinding hard when trying to put it in gear?

Answer (score 2):

It would only cause issues if any parts or fragments of the 5th gear or its mechanism etc were excessivly worn or damaged, and left floating around inside the gearbox.
If there is just an external linkage issue, it will likely only be an inconvenience for you, however an external linkage issue is also quite easy to repair. Either way it would be an idea to have it checked out.